# Disable buttons through Radio button

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have 2 Radio buttons in my requirement. 
Single Field Scrambler and Multi field Scrambler. 
User must select the “Single field scrambler” or “Multi field scrambler” radio button based on the scrambling requirement.

If user selects “Single field scrambler”, the below buttons should be disabled and they must select a field required for scrambling.

- Select Config File
- View Config File
- Modify Config File

This is my Radio Button List Code

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal"OnSelectedIndexChanged="RadioButtonList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
<asp:ListItem Text="Single Field Scrambler" Value="singlefieldscramble">    </asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Text="Multi Field Scrambler" Value="multifieldscramble"></asp:ListItem> </asp:RadioButtonList>
```

How can we disable buttons when user clicks "Single Field Scrambler".
 Any Help Please.

Comment: How about you disable them? What have you tried?

Comment: protected void RadioButtonList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {                                                                                           btnvcf.Enabled = false;                                                                           btnmcf.Enabled = false;
DropDownConfigFile.Enabled = false;                                                                          }tried like this. But didnt worked

Comment: Just call an JavaScript function and set these fields to .disabled = true;

Answer (score 1):

You can call SelectedIndexChanged event for the radio buttons like this,

```
protected void RadioButtonList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(RadioButtonList1.SelectedItem.ToString()=="Single field scrambler" || RadioButtonList1.SelectedItem.ToString()=="singlefieldscrambler")
    {
       btnvcf.Enabled = false; 
       btnmcf.Enabled = false; 
       DropDownConfigFile.Enabled = false;
    }
}
```

similar code for the radio button list is  here:
http://asp-net-example.blogspot.in/2009/03/how-to-use-onselectedindexchanged-event_18.html

Comment: Here If condition is not taking the Single filed scaramble value. Which value I need to pass.

Comment: see the code now, i have added the condition, compare it with any value that you have it in your radio button text.(which is displayed on the form)

Comment: protected void RadioButtonList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (singlefieldscramble.Text = "Single field scrambler")                                                                        btnvcf.enable = false.                                
        }                                                                                                                           here singlefieldscramble is my radio button value. but it is saying like singlefieldscramble does not exist in the context.

Comment: Singlefieldscramble should be the control name, not the value. Look my code above. Use the name of the control

Comment: Please have a look at code now i have edited the code as per your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You can call SelectedIndexChanged event for the radio buttons like this:

```
protected void RadioButtonList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgse){
    for (int i = 0; i < RadioButtonList1.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        if (RadioButtonList1.Items[i].Selected == true)
        {
            RadioButtonList2.Items[i].Selected = false;
            RadioButtonList2.Items[i].Enabled = false;
        }
        if (RadioButtonList1.Items[i].Selected != true)
        {
            RadioButtonList2.Items[i].Enabled = true;
        }
    }
}
```